# jQuery Object Literal Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, design-patterns, object-literal

In an effort to write cleaner code i have decided to learn some design patterns. I really love the Object Literal Module pattern, but im having a bit of trouble. I have created a lightbox in spaghetti code and have not been able to convert it to a object literal pattern.

```
var $overlay = $("<div class='lightbox'></div>");
var $img = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p class='caption'></p>");



$overlay
    .append($img)
    .append($caption);



$('body').append($overlay);


$('.gallery li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var src = $(this).children('img').attr("src");
    var cap = $(this).children('img').attr("alt");

    $img.attr('src',src);
    $caption.text(cap);

    $overlay.fadeIn('fast');

    $overlay.click(function () {
        $overlay.fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome JamJam, what is your question exactly? Which parts do you want to convert?

Comment: @A1rPun Hello, if possible all of it. I recently read this [link](https://css-tricks.com/can-you-over-organize-javascript/) where he turned some components written in jquery to the object literal pattern, im attempting to restructure the code above into an object literal pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've refactored the code into an object literal using the same kind of structure you linked with your post. All created elements are in the `lightbox.el` namespace and you initiate the lightbox with `lightbox.init()`.

```
var lightbox = {
    el: {
        overlay: $("<div class='lightbox'></div>"),
        img: $("<img>"),
        caption: $("<p class='caption'></p>"),
        galleryItems: $('.gallery li'),
        body: $('body')
    },
    fadeSpeed: 'fast',
    init: function(){
        lightbox.append();
        lightbox.bindUIActions();
    },
    bindUIActions: function(){
        lightbox.el.galleryItems.click(lightbox.handleGalleryClick);
    },
    handleGalleryClick: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var src = $(this).children('img').attr("src");
        var cap = $(this).children('img').attr("alt");

        lightbox.el.img.attr('src',src);
        lightbox.el.caption.text(cap);    
        lightbox.el.overlay.fadeIn(lightbox.fadeSpeed);    
        lightbox.el.overlay.click(lightbox.fadeOutOverlay);
    },
    fadeOutOverlay: function(){
        lightbox.el.overlay.fadeOut(lightbox.fadeSpeed);
    },
    append: function(){
        lightbox.el.overlay
            .append(lightbox.el.img)
            .append(lightbox.el.caption);
        lightbox.el.body.append(lightbox.el.overlay);
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
lightbox.init();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to get it right for 2 days and i now see what my mistakes were. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why using the object name _lightbox_ instead of 'this' and 'var self = this'?

Comment: @jacopo.galli You can use `this` if you like. The link in OP's question used the variable instead of `this` so I stuck with the same convention.